# Как в один столбец записать несколько значений?

Tags: sql

Есть таблица, например User, у которой несколько столбцов

```
CREATE TABLE USER
(
  PR_KEY            VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR2(100 CHAR),
  surname VARCHAR2(100 CHAR)
)
```

Требуется создать эту таблицу на SQL с еще одним столбцом, но, в этом столбце должны быть размещены несколько значений, например, список строк - номеров комнат, в который пользователь имеет доступ

Как это сделать через еще одну таблицу и как значения из другой таблицы будут подставляться в основную?

Comment: Какую именно СУБД используете?

Comment: И что именно хотите: писать в один столбец несколько значений или использовать дополнительную таблицу?

Comment: прочитайте про `foreign key`

Answer (score 1):

Для решения данной задачи Вам необходимо создать таблицу комнаты

С колонками id, name, num_room ... (Остальные свойства характеризующие комнаты). Далее нужно понимать вашу задачу
1. Если к пользователю прикреплены несколько комнат и 1 комната может принадлежать только одному пользователю, то Вам необходимо создать в новой таблице поле user_id (типа `integer`, `unsigned`( не может быть  меньше 0) и повесить `index` на данное поле) и далее прочитать о внешних ключах foreign key(домашнее задание Вам) и про `inner join` как в запросе объединить таблицы и получить обеденные данные
2. Если у вас за пользователем может быть закреплено несколько комнат, и к одной комнате могут быть прикреплены несколько пользователей, то здесь связь многие ко многим, то здесь необходимо создать 3 таблицу `user_room` с полями `id` `user_id` `room_id` и то же самое домашнее задание только как создать foreign key со связью многие ко многим

Отвечая на последней вопрос, соединяете таблицы по одному из двух путей далее вы заполняете таблицу `rooms` комната 1, комната 2, комната 3 ... 
И используя `select * from ...` получаете данные уже с комнатами которые присоединены к пользователям!

P.s. обошёлся бы без домашних заданий, но я с телефона. Надеюсь помог)